# Salvar RadioButtom depois da seleção

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, radiobutton

Olá, alguém poderia me ajudar nessa questão, eu tenho uma lista com perguntas nelas exitem 3 RadiosButtom para repostas, o que eu quero é quando o usuário clicar no botão salve, ele liste os radios selecionados e salve em uma lista, do jeito que consegui fazer ele pega os Radios no click do usuário gerando um problema, se o usuário clicar em outro radio da mesma posição da lista ele está guardando os dois radios que foram clicados e guardando na lista que posteriormente eu pego e salvo no SQlite.

Segue a imagem do layout.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código do Adapter.

```
public class ExpandableRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Repo> repos;
    public SparseBooleanArray expandState = new SparseBooleanArray();
    public ArrayList<String> listTxtRadio = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<String> listText = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<Integer> listIDRadio = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public ArrayList<Integer> listId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public Context context;

    public RadioButton radioButton;

    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;

    public ExpandableRecyclerAdapter(List<Repo> repos, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.repos = repos;
        for (int i = 0; i < repos.size(); i++) {
            expandState.append(i, false);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        this.context = viewGroup.getContext();
        if (i == TYPE_HEADER) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header_layout, viewGroup, false);
            return new HeaderVh(view);
        } else if (i == TYPE_ITEM) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_report_list, viewGroup, false);
            return new ItemVh(view);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("No macth for" + i + ".");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        //Header
        final Repo repo = repos.get(position);

        if (viewHolder instanceof HeaderVh) {
            ((HeaderVh) viewHolder).headerTitle.setText(repo.getTitle());
        } else if (viewHolder instanceof ItemVh) {
            ((ItemVh) viewHolder).tvTitleList.setText(repo.getTitle());

            viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
            viewHolder.tvTitleList.setText(repos.get(position).getTitle());
            viewHolder.tvTextList.setText(repos.get(position).getText());

            final boolean isExpanded = expandState.get(position);
            viewHolder.expandableLayout.setVisibility(isExpanded ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

            viewHolder.buttonLayoutArrow.setRotation(expandState.get(position) ? 180f : 0f);
            viewHolder.buttonLayoutArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {
                    onClickButton(viewHolder.expandableLayout, viewHolder.buttonLayoutArrow, position);
                }
            });

            //Test onClick RadioButton
            viewHolder.mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                    int selectedRadioButtonID = viewHolder.mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                    //Test Salve in a ArrayList RadioButton Selected
                    radioButton = group.findViewById(selectedRadioButtonID);

                    String selectedText = (String) viewHolder.tvTitleList.getText();
                    String selectedRadioButtonText = radioButton.getText().toString();
                    int selectedRadioId = radioButton.getId();

                    listIDRadio.add(selectedRadioId);
                    listId.add(position);
                    listText.add(selectedText);
                    listTxtRadio.add(selectedRadioButtonText);

                    Log.i("log", "Item: " + listTxtRadio + " listRadio ");
                    Log.i("log", "Item: " + listId + " selectedIDList ");
                    Log.i("log", "Item: " + listIDRadio + " selectedIDRadio ");
                    Log.i("log", "Item: " + listText + " listText ");

                    //Del duplicate list
                            /*HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>(listText);
                            hashSet.addAll(listText);
                            listText.clear();
                            listText.addAll(hashSet);
                            repo.setCheckList(listText);
                            Log.position("log", "Item: " + repo.getCheckList() + " getCheckList ");*/

                            /*if (checkedId == R.id.radio_conform) {
                                viewHolder.mRadioButtonConform.setChecked(true);
                                group.setTag(checkedId);
                                //Log.position("log", "Item: " + listConformed + " listConformed ");

                            } else if (checkedId == R.id.radio_not_applicable) {
                                viewHolder.mRadioButtonNotApplicable.setChecked(true);
                                group.setTag(checkedId);
                                //Log.position("log", "Item: " + listNotConformed + " listNotConformed ");

                            } else if (checkedId == R.id.radio_not_conform) {
                                viewHolder.mRadioButtonNotConform.setChecked(true);
                                group.setTag(checkedId);
                                //Log.position("log", "Item: " + listNotApplicable + " listNotApplicable ");

                            } else {
                                group.clearCheck();
                            }*/
                }
            });
            // End RadioButton
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "onBindViewHolder invoked" + position);
    }

    public int getItemViewType(int i) {
        if (isPositionHeader(i))
            return TYPE_HEADER;
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    private boolean isPositionHeader(int i) {
        return i == 0 || i == 21 || i == 30;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return repos.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tvTitleList, tvTextList;
        ImageView mImageView;

        public RadioGroup mRadioGroup;
        public RadioButton mRadioButtonConform;
        public RadioButton mRadioButtonNotApplicable;
        public RadioButton mRadioButtonNotConform;

        RelativeLayout buttonLayoutArrow;
        public LinearLayout expandableLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            tvTitleList = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_title);
            tvTextList = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_subTitle);
            mImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.photo);
            mRadioGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
            mRadioButtonConform = view.findViewById(R.id.radio_conform);
            mRadioButtonNotApplicable = view.findViewById(R.id.radio_not_applicable);
            mRadioButtonNotConform = view.findViewById(R.id.radio_not_conform);

            buttonLayoutArrow = view.findViewById(R.id.btnArrow);
            expandableLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.expandableLayout);
        }
    }

    //Header
    public class HeaderVh extends ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.header_id)
        public TextView headerTitle;

        public HeaderVh(@NonNull View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }
    }

    public class ItemVh extends ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.textView_title)
        public TextView itemContent;


        public ItemVh(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }

    private void onClickButton(final LinearLayout expandableLayout, final RelativeLayout buttonLayout, final int i) {

        //Expand CardView
        if (expandableLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            createRotateAnimator(buttonLayout, 180f, 0f).start();
            expandableLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            expandState.put(i, false);
        } else {
            createRotateAnimator(buttonLayout, 0f, 180f).start();
            expandableLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            expandState.put(i, true);
        }

    }

    //Animation Expand
    private ObjectAnimator createRotateAnimator(final View target, final float from, final float to) {
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "rotation", from, to);
        animator.setDuration(300);
        animator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        return animator;

    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente desculpe qualquer coisa, mas estou digitando do celular

Pelo o que percebi, seu problema está no momento de adicionar o Radio que vc identificou que foi pressionado nas suas listas (`listId, listIDRadio, etc`).

Repare que vc está adicionando os elementos referentes aos RadioButtons nas listas **dentro do onCheckedChanged EventListener,** ou seja, o código de dentro desse método é chamado toda vez que o Radio que está selecionado for alterado!

Para resolver isso vc pode deixar de lado o EventListener e simplesmente usar o método `mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()`, que retornará -1 se nenhum Radio estiver selecionado ou então retorna o Id do botão selecionado (int)

Repare ainda que se vc tiver ids para cada um dos seus RadioButtons em seu layout, vc pode pegar esse id retornado pela função e verificar se o Radio foi pressionado pelo nome dele no layout:

```
if(myRadioId == R.id.nome_do_radio){

//Executa algo
}
```

De novo peço que me Desculpe se tiver algo de errado! Estou as 4h40 de uma noite de insônia digitando no celular hehe

Comment: Olá Quik19, primeiramente muito obrigado pelo retorno e de ter tirado um tempo para me ajudar, bom sobre esse caso até entendi o que me passou, mas não conseguir implementar... pode ser por falta de experiência, não conseguir usar o método getCheckedRadioButtonId() na minha recyclerView e pegar os resultados na minha Activity que gerencia a recyclerView e o botão Salvar. Você teria algum código que trabalhe com essa lógica?

Comment: Não sei como seu código está estruturado para saber o que suas classes podem enxergar ou não, mas a ideia é que vc adicione algum botão de Salvar, e dentro do onClick() desse botão você recupere o dado do RadioGroup (qual RadioButton foi selecionado). Dessa maneira você não utilizará um Listener, ou então a cada seleção feita pelo usuário as informações serão atualizadas. Além disso repare que o getCheckedRadioButtonId() é um método do RadioGroup, e não da ReciclerView. Vc tbm pode (e deve) recuperar essas informações direto na sua Activity que tem o RadioGroup ao invés de no Adapter